# How to click data-bind input on login.microsoftonline.com for nightwatchjs

Tags: azure, nightwatch.js

I have tried to click to NO or YES on login.microsoftonline.com on the Stay signed in? dialog and I cant get pass this page, checking the code this page has

There is no frames on the page :(

```
<input value="Yes" aria-describedby="KmsiDescription" id="idSIButton9" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-bind="
        attr: {
            'id': primaryButtonId || 'idSIButton9',
            'aria-describedby': primaryButtonDescribedBy },
        value: primaryButtonText() || str['CT_PWD_STR_SignIn_Button_Next'],
        hasFocus: focusOnPrimaryButton,
        click: primaryButton_onClick,
        enable: isPrimaryButtonEnabled,
        visible: isPrimaryButtonVisible" type="submit">

 <input value="No" id="idBtn_Back" class="btn btn-block" data-bind="
        attr: {
            'id': secondaryButtonId || 'idBtn_Back',
            'aria-describedby': secondaryButtonDescribedBy },
        value: secondaryButtonText() || str['CT_HRD_STR_Splitter_Back'],
        hasFocus: focusOnSecondaryButton,
        click: secondaryButton_onClick,
        enable: isSecondaryButtonEnabled,
        visible: isSecondaryButtonVisible" type="button">
```

Please anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is this page in the same frame?
If not then  you may have to switch to the right frame and then select the button.
In order to select the button you may use SelectBy ID etc.
Or else you may use JavaScriptexecutor to execute the Javascript event to select the button.
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **Yes** button has the id `idSIButton9`. You should be able to just use that.

```
browser.click('#idSIButton9');
```

Or even this should work

```
browser.click('input[value="Yes"]');
```